# Transposing a text file in Python

Tags: python

I have a text file that I would like to transpose using Python.

For example, given the following file:

```
asdfg
qwert
```

I would like the output of the script to be a text file containing:

```
aq
sw
de
fr
gt
```

What is the simplest, most 'pythonic' way to go about this? The most I've been able to come up with myself is to read the data of the first file into an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Setup**

First lets set up our file for those of us who haven't set it up, but you can skip to the read part below, just ensure you change the filepath variable to reflect the location and name of your file:

```
import textwrap

              # dedent removes the extra whitespace in front of each line
text = textwrap.dedent("""
    asdfg
    qwert""").strip() # strip takes off the first newline

filepath = '/temp/foo.txt'

with open(filepath, 'w') as writer:
    writer.write(text)
```

**Read the file**

So now we have our file in place, let's read it back in to the text variable, using the `with` context manager (so if we have an error, it automatically closes the file for us, and we can easily recover.):

```
with open(filepath, 'rU') as reader:
    text = reader.read()
```

**Manipulate the text**

And here's the magic, split the lines of the text so that we have a list of two strings, expand that list into two arguments (with the `*`) passed to `zip`, which then goes through the strings by character pairwise, joining the pairs with an empty string, and then we print each member of that list:

```
list_of_strings = [''.join(chars) for chars in zip(*text.splitlines())]

for string_i in list_of_strings:
    print(string_i)
```

should print

```
aq
sw
de
fr
gt
```

Comment: It seems to almost work, but there is a problem with the way the file is initially created. There are extra spaces at the beginning of the second line that cause problems when it comes time to print it out later. Sorry if this is a simple bug -- kind of new to this

Comment: If you add spaces, that will happen. I can show you a module that can handle that, though.

Comment: Is it possible to just read in an existing file by skipping the write part and replacing the path?

Comment: @erythraios yes, that's the intention here, but the way I did it, anyone can replicate it. Note I demo'd this on Windows, but it should work on Mac and Unix too.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `readlines()` to get a list for each line.

And for a clean approach, try zip:

```
a = "asdfg"
b = "qwert"

print zip(a, b)
```

Gives:

```
[('a', 'q'), ('s', 'w'), ('d', 'e'), ('f', 'r'), ('g', 't')]
```

From there, iterate over each element and print out the results.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is you wanted:

```
with open("/Users/wy/Desktop/wy.txt", "r") as cin:
    lines = cin.read()
lineStr = lines.split('\n')

with open("/Users/wy/Desktop/res.txt", "w") as cout:
    for ele in zip(*lineStr):
        cout.write(''.join(list(ele)) + '\n')
```